# As if one were ever required

Tags: grammar

I this morning commented on a picture of my female friend and that was taken in a stunning backdrop and she herself is very beautiful. And I commented the following this morning on that picture using the following sentence, but later I got confused about it and was wondering if what I used was correct or not.

"The scenic backdrop in the picture accentuates your beauty, ***as if you ever needed one***."

Now is the above sentence correct and if yes, then does it make sense in this context to use it? If yes, then please tell me what it means. I just happened to write that, without any idea as to what it means. So please help me decipher it.

Thank you.

Comment: It's correct enough to be understandable (I'll let others dissect the actual grammar, as I'm not a grammar person, but a "word" person :D). And given your description of the situation - the meaning will also be understood as you explained the intent - that you find her beautiful and that it is apparent enough without having to put her in a beautiful background/setting.

Comment: It's tangled, but "one" refers to "scenic backdrop": "The scenic backdrop in the picture accentuates your beauty (as if you ever needed a scenic backdrop to accentuate your beauty)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "The scenic backdrop in the picture accentuates your beauty, as if you ever needed one.", the *"one"* refers to **"the action of accentuating her beauty"**, not the backdrop itself.  Because you're then talking about a verb, not a noun, that, it would be better to say

"..., as if you ever needed **it**."

Comment: Max sir, what is confusing me is this. On the hand the sentence says the beauty is enhanced and on the other my use of 'as if' says t'he action of accentuating her beauty' is not required at all. Because it does not in actuality enhance the beauty. So in light of this, what I said as a complement stands true? I am just confused by the seeming contradictory senses conveyed by the sentence. Can you please tell me how to understand the usage of the above sentence? Thank you.

Comment: It's still a compliment - it's two compliments really.  First of all you are saying that she has beauty ("The scenic backdrop in the picture accentuates (ie makes more strong) your beauty") and then you go on to add that she is so beautiful already that her beauty doesn't need to be accentuated.  The "as if" isn't saying "The backdrop **doesn't** accentuate your beauty", it's saying that her beauty is "strong" enough to not need accentuating at all.

Comment: Max sir, could you give your valued insight on this question, please?

http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93076/confusion-about-using-either-simple-past-or-present-perfect?noredirect=1#comment180991_93076